# directional dependence vs direction dependence

Tags: nouns

Are both "direction dependence" and "directional dependence" correct? I thought the former is incorrect, but a lot of examples appear in google.

Answer (score -1):

I had no idea what either of these means, or if one is a misspelling of the other, but using logic and English grammar...

"*Direction dependence*" should logically mean dependence on direction. Like someone who is 'alcohol dependent' is dependent on alcohol.

"*Directional dependence*" - should logically mean dependence that operates in a particular direction. Like a 'directional microphone' picks up sound coming from one particular direction. Of the two, this latter doesn't make very much sense without context.

Looking on Google, it seems that "*directional* dependency" is "a method to determine the likely causal direction of effect between two variables", whereas "*direction* dependence" is "the asymmetry between cause and effect".